# Enumerating domains in Prolog's clpfd

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm exploring dependent structures of constraints like this one:

```
assign(X,Y) :- 
    X in 1..5, 
    ((X mod 2 #= 1) #=> Y in 2..3), 
    ((X mod 2 #= 0) #=> Y #= 5).
```

What I'm looking for is a representation of `X`'s and `Y`'s domains that is as sparse as possible - in this case it would be something along the lines of `X in {1,3,5} and Y in {2,3} or X in {2,4} and Y = 5`.

One way of doing that would be to detect all variables on the left side of the `#=>`, enumerate all their values and collect and merge them together, something like `?- assign(X, Y), findall(X-D, (indomain(X),fd_dom(Y,D)), C), do stuff with C`, but maybe there is a more efficient way?

I've also encountered an error trying to `label([X,Y])`: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated that goes away when I add another constraint on `Y`'s domain.

When should I expect this error to occur? I feel I have a poor understanding of clpfd's mechanisms and limitations, are there any resources I could learn from? I already know the basics of constraint programming, arc consistency etc.

Comment: Did you mean `#==>` in your code rather than `#=>`? `label([X,Y])` requires that there be some domain definition on `X` and `Y`.. Otherwise you get an instantiation error. If the condition, `X mod 2 #= 1` is false, what is the domain of `Y`?

Comment: `#==>` and `#=>` mean the same thing, one is swi-prolog and the other is sicstus. When `X mod 2 #= 1` is false the other implication is true, so `Y` is just 5. So specifying some finite domain for each variable should be enough to avoid the instantiation error?

Comment: OK thanks. I didn't see that in the documentation. `label([X,Y])` requires a domain for each variable, so that would indeed avoid the error.

Comment: @Pyetras. `X mod 2 #= 0` and `X mod 2 #= 1` *are* mutually exclusive but clpfd may not be able to derive that `Y in (2..3)\/{5}` must hold. Declare finite domains for all variables you use in clpfd-constraints before any enumeration goals (indomain, label, labeling, solve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep clpfd enumeration predicates (like `indomain/1`, `label/1`, `labeling/2`, etc.) from *ever* throwing instantiation errors, simply ensure that **all** variables have been assigned some **finite** domain *before* any enumeration predicates is executed.

So how about directly translating what you wrote to code?

```
assign(X,Y) :- X in 1\/3\/5, Y in 2..3.     %    X in {1,3,5} and Y in {2,3} 
assign(X,Y) :- X in 2..4,    Y in 5.        % or X in {2,4}   and Y = 5
```

A simple query (with SWI-Prolog):

```
?- assign(X,Y), labeling([],[X,Y]).
  X = 1, Y = 2
; X = 1, Y = 3
; X = 3, Y = 2
; X = 3, Y = 3
; X = 5, Y = 2
; X = 5, Y = 3
; X = 2, Y = 5
; X = 3, Y = 5
; X = 4, Y = 5.
```